# How to keep reading from an InputStream as long as there is something in it (Android/Java)?

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I'm using a REST API to get input from a hardware keypad. I'd like to know how to keep reading from an `InputStream` as long as there is input, and then stop gracefully without throwing a `SocketTimoutException`.

MY CODE

```
// Start a new thread for reading the keyboard input
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {

            // Set byte stream from response body
            inputStream = response.body().byteStream();

            // I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM. WHILE (TRUE) //
            while (true) {

                // This is where the rest response is read into an array of bytes. I interpret this array below and it seems to work as intended.
                final byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                // This was more for debugging purposes... it never get invoked, as far as I can tell.
                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "...Returning. 0 bytes read.");
                    return;
                }

                // I'll specify what a response looks like below this code block.
                String fullResponse = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Log.v(TAG, "...Full rest response : \n " + fullResponse);

                // This processes the response, narrowing down to just the keycode. This works as it's supposed to.
                processResponse(fullResponse);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v(TAG, "...Problem reading input stream");

        } finally {

            // Close input stream when I'm done with it.
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

So here is an example of a response I get from the rest api. My `processResponse()` method locates and updates a text view with my pressed keycodes (in this case 34). This is working as intended.

```
...Full rest response : 

timeout: 2000000                                                              
event: keypress                                                                    
id: 1492005344                                                                      
data: {"device":"keyboard","pressedKeycodes":"34 "}
```

What I want to know is how to keep reading from the `InputStream` as long as something is there, and stop after receiving no more input without throwing a `SockoutTimeoutException`. If I don't do this `while(true)` I don't get an exception but it only reads one keypad press.

Here is the exception:

```
04-12 15:18:02.467 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
04-12 15:18:02.469 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
04-12 15:18:02.470 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
04-12 15:18:02.471 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
04-12 15:18:02.472 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
04-12 15:18:02.473 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:238)
04-12 15:18:02.474 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:66)
04-12 15:18:02.475 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:59)
04-12 15:18:02.476 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.java:284)
04-12 15:18:02.477 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1xStream.java:441)
04-12 15:18:02.478 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:422)
04-12 15:18:02.479 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
04-12 15:18:02.479 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
04-12 15:18:02.480 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:279)
04-12 15:18:02.481 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:386)
04-12 15:18:02.482 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at com.accutime.restpractice.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:172)
04-12 15:18:02.483 7585-7810/com.accutime.restpractice W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: `stop gracefully without throwing a SocketTimoutException.` Sorry but i see no socket in your code. And you did not tell how your keyboard is connected to your Android device. Shouldn't you start with it?

Comment: `if (bytesRead < 0) {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "...Returning. 0 bytes read.");
                                    return;
                                }` You are out then. Better change to `if (bytesRead < 0) { continue;}`

Comment: `String fullResponse = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. No. Not the whole buffer. Only the readed bytes. Change to something like: `String fullResponse = new String(buffer, bytesRead, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`.

Comment: I followed the two above comments and I'm still getting an exception. See my updated question.

Comment: To be clear, I would like this thread to be running indefinitely, responding to keypresses at any time without timing out.

Comment: If you dont press a key then you will eventually get a socket timeout exceptiom. But what does it matter? Catch that exception and connect again. All in a outher loop.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create a utility class that read an `InputStream` and return a `byte[]` of content read. Suppose the utility class, in this example, is called `InputOutputStreams`.

My method will then be:

```
public static byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

I will then remove the `while` loop you have (and various implementations) and use the utility class implemented above to retrieve the content of my `InputStream`, like so:

```
    // Start a new thread for reading the keyboard input
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    try {

                        // Set byte stream from response body
                        inputStream = response.body().byteStream();

                            // I'll specify what a response looks like below this code block.
                            //THIS IS WHERE I USE THE UTILITY CLASS
                            String fullResponse = new String(InputOutputStreams.readFully(inputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                            Log.v(TAG, "...Full rest response : \n " + fullResponse);

                            // This processes the response, narrowing down to just the keycode. This works as it's supposed to.
                            processResponse(fullResponse);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.v(TAG, "...Problem reading input stream");

                    } finally {

                        // Close input stream when I'm done with it.
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            try {
                                inputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: What is writer? I'm assuming you mean baos but this isn't giving me any response now

Comment: I'm getting the same problem that it never escapes while (input.read(buffer) > 0) { and eventually throws a SocketTimeoutException. Any ideas what to do about this?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my problem. The code in the question body can be kept the same, but when I created my retrofit builder I needed to add an OkHttpClient with `read timeout` and `write timeout` of `max value`.

This causes the program not to time out with a `SocketNotFound` exception, and input will happily be accepted for a lengthy period of time.

Here's my code:

```
    // TODO 9 : Set a timeout for the connection // <- I NEEDED TO ADD THIS BLOCK ***
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .readTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    // TODO 7 : Create retrofit builder
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ClockAPI.ENDPOINT) // Refers to endpoint defined in GithubAPI
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) // Refers to gson builder, created
            .client(okHttpClient) // <- AND THIS LINE ***
            .build();

    // TODO 8 : Create REST API through retrofit builder
    clockUserAPI = retrofit.create(ClockAPI.class);
```